# Stretch font vertically in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to stretch some font like the below image (only vertically stretch, not horizontally). Is it possible? Or will I have to use an SVG/Image instead.

Thanks

[image: Stretched Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vertical stretching, you can use the css `transform` property and scale it along the Y axis like so

```css
p{
  font-size:50px;
  transform: scale(1, 5);
}
```

```html
<p>Some Text</p>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.